# Affine Transform in PDF

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I seem to be missing something related to how Affine Transform works in PDF. I have a requirement to do below -

- A shape whose bottom-left edge located in origin
- Rotate the shape to 90 deg Counter-Clockwise
- Translate the shape to the destination

Now, when i apply affine transform, i am not getting the proper placement of the shape in the destination. After several experiments, i found that PDF Engines apply rotation AROUND the bottom-left corner of the shape as reference, but most literature guides rotation about the center axis, suggesting no difference would occur doing either way.

But i am not able to get correct arithmetic behind my transform ad i am unable to achieve the result. I am not very sound in Mathematics, hence, would appreciate any help in achieving this.

Prepare some illustrations to show how i am doing the transform.

[image]

[image]

[image]

My understanding of the math behind the transform may be wrong altogether and would appreciate if i can get some guidance. I am using PDFBox to achieve the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you overcomplicate this. But I'm not sure because you don't explain what the problem exactly is, in which way you are *not getting the proper placement of the shape in the destination*.

Comment: Have you considered explaining your issue more precisely?